# wireless driver crashes windows 8.1 randomly

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, crash

I have a toshiba satellite laptop which came with windows 7, I installed windows 8.1 onto it successfully. Then one day I get a pop up from some inbuilt toshiba software saying that it wants to update my wireless driver I install the driver, but I believe it to be an old driver possibly intended for windows 7. The laptop crashed randomly a few times after until a few days later when it would crash when I try to boot unless in safe mode, it would give me this error:

:(
system_thread_exception_not_handled(athwbx.sys)

I used my laptop with the wireless driver disabled for a while and bought a new SSD and ended up installing a fresh copy of windows 8.1 onto it. I thought this had fixed the problem, but the random crashing is back with exactly the same error. The driver I currently have installed is:

wireless atheros ar9002wb-1ng

I'm almost certain it is a problem with the driver, but have no idea how to fix. Do I need to download a new or old driver?

Comment: get the latest Atheros driver: http://www.atheros.cz/

Answer (score 0):

It should be an issue with your Wireless driver. Download the recent wireless driver from the vendor site and the driver file ready in the machine. Reboot the machine in "Safe Mode" and uninstall it from "Uninstall or Change a Program". Now, reboot the machine in normal mode and run the downloaded wireless driver OR go to Device Manager (windows key+r > mmc devmgmt.msc) and click on "Scan for Hardware Changes" and update the downloaded driver.

Hope this helps.